# Codeigniter join returning same record three times

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have one record in listing table one in property_address table and three images in property_images table which belong to that one record in listing table. Now what actually i want to return a single row have all the images. But what i am getting is  3 rows and is because of that 3 images with every image in property images table it create a new row.

I have three tables

1. listing
2. property_address
3. property_images

**Here is the Schema**.
[image: Database Schema]

**Here is Model function.**

```
public function get_listing($where)
    {
        $this->db->select('dl.*,pi.*,ps.*');
        $this->db->from('listing as dl');
        $this->db->join('property_address as ps','ps.property_add_id=dl.prop_id');
        $this->db->join('property_images as pi','pi.listing_id=dl.prop_id','right');
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Here is controller**.

```
public function testin()
    {
        $data=$this->dba->get_listing(array('dl.prop_id'=>2));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Comment: You can do `echo $this->db->last_query();` after query in your controller, to see the MySQL query, and use that query to execute in phpmyadmin to see, if there is problem with query or not!

Comment: query is running perfect problem is with same multiple records but with different images

Comment: The result is expected.you have 3 row at `property_images` so result will be 3.You should provide example how you want one row.

Answer (score 1):

Well Actually it probably will return 3 records because property_address table has relation with listing table and when you join and retrieve record it will return 3 record on the base of foreign keys and on the base of your query.

What you should do is to manage the record in programming way like if you have 3 same record with different image fetch the same record individually and than loop over images for example.

Example:

```
public function testin()
    {
        $data=$this->dba->get_listing(array('dl.prop_id'=>2));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo $data[0]->id;
        echo $data[0]->title;
        echo $data[0]->prop_type;
        echo $data[0]->property_name;
        echo $data[0]->addres;
        etc....
        Now loop over images and you will get all three images
        foreach($data as $row):
        {
          echo $data->image;
        }
```

}

I hope it will help.

Comment: so it means i have to utilize data in programing way doesnt really matter if have multiple same record with only a single different column like in the situation i am

Comment: @Vicky It will work only for single listing item.For multiple listing item you need do it different way.Hope you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Left join** is what you are looking for,

```
public function get_listing($where)
{
    $this->db->select('dl.*,pi.*,ps.*');
    $this->db->from('listing as dl');
    $this->db->join('property_address as ps','ps.property_add_id=dl.prop_id','left');
    $this->db->join('property_images as pi','pi.listing_id=dl.prop_id','right','left');
    if(!empty($where))
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: still getting 3 same rows